# How to display a warning message using jQuery in odoo 9

Tags: jquery, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I would like to show an warning message in odoo using jQuery. Because I am doing the validation in jQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `do_warn` method [odoo-9:FormView.load_record](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js#L358).

```
this.do_warn(_t("Form"), _t("The record could not be found in the database."), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **do_warn,do_notify** kind of browser's notification method's for displaying error message or warning using jquery. Apart from that you can also use `throw new Error` kind of constructor.